# Wait for function to finish before ajax call starts

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty sure I'm being stupid here as it's approaching the end of the day. But when I submit my form (generated dynamically) how would I first complete the close function before I try and open my new lightbox with ajax. At the moment they happen simultaniously so my close function is closing the lighbox I'm trying to open.

```
// Submit form
$(":submit").live('click', function() {

    // Prevent default
    event.preventDefault();

    // Close previous lightbox
    lb.close();

    // Open new lightbox
    $.ajax({
        // Blah blah blah
    });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add or use a callback function.

```
// Submit form
$(":submit").live('click', function() {

    // Prevent default
    event.preventDefault();

    // Close previous lightbox
    lb.close(function(){

        // Open new lightbox
        $.ajax({
            // Blah blah blah
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: If you can post the link to the lightbox plugin you are using I can check it out and see if it has a callback function.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't so I had to add one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If .close() has no callback, then just use setTimeout().